# Osgi commandline install multiple plugins simultaneously

Tags: console, osgi, osgi-bundle

Is it possible to simultaneously load all the plugins available in a directory in osgi commandline?

```
path/to/bin/java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806 -console -clean
```

This brought up the osgi console and activated the org.eclipse. `ss` shows me this

```
id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.1.R36x_v20100806
```

I have a bunch of bundles in a directory: `/path/to/all/bundles`
I can certainly do one-by-one on the osgi console using the following:

```
osgi> install file:///path/to/bundle/org.springframework.osgi.core
```

I want to be able to load all bundles at once and next step is to be able to install it as well.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you definitely don't want to install all your bundles by hand every time. Installing the single [Apache FileInstall](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-file-install.html) bundle will then automatically load anything you put into a directory (./load) by default.

Comment: thanks for your answer..I will certainly try this and update you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in using [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org) it does give you Features, where features is a set of bundles defined in either maven-locations or file-locations. Besides this it also gives you a lot of other benefits for working with OSGi bundles, just for an example you'll have more then 200 commands to work with in the shell and lots of them will help you find problems with your bundles.

Comment: thanks for your answer!...I will look into this direction as well...1 quick question, i am currently playing around with Osgi container...but my requirement is to build a equinox based product ultimately(apologize...I did not clarify this in my question as it could be too specific) ..can Apache Karaf container be used in lieu of equinox as it is?...thank you!

Comment: Karaf is a osgi Container where your able to either use Felix or Equinox as the underlying osgi framework.